# How to plot multiple data points on the same graph using google charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

This was an attempt to solve a LP graphical problem. I would like to solve 2 linear equations on the same graph but being a beginner in data visualization, I found it hard to address my problem. My failed code goes like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['X', 'Y'],
      [ 0,      120],
      [ 80,      0]
    ]);
    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['X', 'Y'],
      [ 0,      140],
      [ 70,      0]
    ]);

    var options1 = {
      title: 'X and Y',
      hAxis: {title: 'Age' },
      vAxis: {title: 'Weight'},
      legend: 'none',
      trendlines: { 0: {} }
     };
    var options2 = {
      title: 'X and Y',
      hAxis: {title: 'Age' },
      vAxis: {title: 'Weight'},
      legend: 'none',
      trendlines: { 0: {} }
     };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
    chart.draw(data1, options1);
  }
     var chart = new     google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    chart.draw(data2, options2);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
   <body>
   <div id="chart_div1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  <div id="chart_div2" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a second set of points on a ScatterChart, you just need to add another column of data:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['X', 'Y1', 'Y2'],
        [0, 120, 140],
        [70, null, 0],
        [80, 0, null]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'X and Y',
        hAxis: {title: 'Age' },
        vAxis: {title: 'Weight'},
        legend: 'none',
        trendlines: {0: {}, 1: {}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

Insert `null` where a data series does not have a value for a given value of X.  jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/n3EjL/

If you want to draw two charts, you were on the right track, you just have a syntax error: your second chart is outside the `drawChart` function.  It works if you use this:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['X', 'Y'],
        [0, 120],
        [80, 0]
    ]);
    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['X', 'Y'],
        [0, 140],
        [70, 0]
    ]);

    var options1 = {
        title: 'X and Y',
        hAxis: {title: 'Age' },
        vAxis: {title: 'Weight'},
        legend: 'none',
        trendlines: {0: {}, 1: {}}
    };

    var options2 = {
        title: 'X and Y',
        hAxis: {title: 'Age' },
        vAxis: {title: 'Weight'},
        legend: 'none',
        trendlines: {0: {}, 1: {}}
    };

    var chart1 = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
    chart1.draw(data1, options1);
    var chart2 = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    chart2.draw(data2, options2);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/n3EjL/2/